# Definability of defining classes

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

Suppose that $M$ is a transitive class, denote by $\mathrm{HOD}(M)$ the class of all those sets which are hereditarily definable from ordinals and parameters in $M$.

Some trivial examples include $\mathrm{HOD}(V)=V$, and $\rm HOD(Ord)=HOD$. Note that this model might not satisfy the axiom of choice, for example if $M=V$ and $V$ does not satisfy the axiom of choice.

> Is it possible for $M$ to be an inner model of $\sf ZFC$ such that $M$ is not definable (with parameters) in $\mathrm{HOD}(M)$?

Alternatively, we can consider $L(M)$ as the smallest model of $\sf ZF$ such that $M\cap V_\alpha\in L(M)$ for all $\alpha$. Is $M$ always a class of $L(M)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this can happen.

Let's start in $L$ and first perform Easton forcing to add a Cohen
subset to every regular cardinal, giving rise to the forcing
extension $L[G]$. Next, over $L[G]$ we force to code every set into
the GCH pattern, for example, by iterating the forcing that forces
GCH or its negation with a lottery sum at each such cardinal stage.
In the resulting forcing extension $V=L[G][H]$, we therefore have
$\newcommand\HOD{\text{HOD}}\HOD^V=V$, since every set is coded.

Next, over $V$, force to add a $V$-generic class
$A$ of the regular cardinals. This forcing adds no sets,
and $A$ is not a definable class in $V$, but we may consider it in
GBC. Let $M=L[G\upharpoonright A]$ be the inner model arising by
taking only the sets of $G$ at coordinates in $A$. So this is a
transitive inner model of $V$, but it is not first-order definable
in $V$, since $A$ is generic over $V$.

But meanwhile,
$\text{HOD}(M)$ as computed in $V$ will be the same as $\HOD$,
since it is already all of $V$ and so the extra parameters of $M$
didn't add anything.

So we have an inner model $M$ that is not definable in $\HOD(M)$,
as desired.

Let's now modify the example to produce a model $V$ of ZFC with a
*definable* inner model $M$, such that $M$ is not definable in
$\HOD(M)$. Start in $L$ as before, and this time, add the class $A$
first, over $L$. In particular, every initial segment of $A$ is in
$L$. Now, over the GBC model $L[A]$, force to add Cohen sets at
every uncountable regular cardinal, forming $L[A][G]$. Finally,
using product forcing rather than an iteration, we may force to
code every set in $L[G]$, and also the classes $G$ and $A$, into
the GCH pattern, producing an extension $V=L[A][G][H]$ in which
$\HOD=L[G]$. (For example, the methods of my paper G. Fuchs, J. D.
Hamkins, J. Reitz, [Set-theoretic
geology](http://jdh.hamkins.org/set-theoreticgeology/) show how to
do this, while also controlling the mantle and the generic $\HOD$.)

Let $M=L[G\upharpoonright A]$. This is a transitive inner model of
ZFC. It is definable in $V$, since the class $G\upharpoonright A$
is definable there. Further, since every initial segment of $A$ is
in $L$, it follows that $L[G\upharpoonright A]\subset L[G]$, which
is the $\HOD$ of $V$, and so $\HOD(M)=\HOD=L[G]$ in $V$. But $A$ is
not definable in $L[G]$, since $A$ and $G$ are mutually generic. So
$M$ is not definable in $L[G]$.

Which is to say, $M$ is a definable transitive inner model of $V$,
but it is not definable in $\HOD(M)$, as you desired.

Comment: I think one should also be able to make a slightly better example, where $M$ is definable in $V$, but not in HOD(M), which you would probably prefer.

Comment: I updated with such an improved example, where M is now definable in V.

Comment: Thanks Joel. Your updated answer is what I had meant, as clearly the idea was for $M$ to be definable in $V$ (I generally reserve the term "class" for "definable class", but I guess I should have been clearer in my phrasing).

Comment: (I'll give it a closer reading tomorrow morning and see if I have any follow up questions. Thanks for the answer!)

Comment: For the record, I would encourage you henceforth to say "definable class" when that is what you mean, since it is a comparatively small minority usage to assume every class is definable, and I recall a few other questions on MO that were misunderstood more seriously because of that misunderstanding.

Comment: Joel, I think this is an issue of whether or not one thinks "in terms" of ZF or NBG/KM when thinking about classes. In the former case, it's clear that classes are only definable classes; whereas in the latter it is clear that classes can include much more information than just what is definable over the class of all sets using a formula with only set variables. I generally think in terms of ZF, which explains why for me "class" means "definable class". (In any case, let me add, "inner model" almost always refers to a definable class, in my experience, so I got that part covered.)

Comment: Well, saying "definable class" is also correct in ZF or ZFC, if that is what you mean, and it avoids the misunderstanding when talking with other set theorists. In my experience, the phrase "inner model" usually means a transitive class model of ZFC that contains all the ordinals, without any definability requirement. But it is true that one often considers inner models that happen to be definable, and these are of course the easiest to describe. Nevertheless, even in the ZFC context, one often is led to want to consider classes that are not definable, such as when performing class forcing.